# Force version of transitive dependency (dependency of dependency) with yarn

Tags: yarnpkg, transitive-dependency, yarn-lock.json

I am using the package `"csv-file-validator": "^1.8.0"` which comes with 3 dependencies

```
 famulus "2.1.2"
 lodash "4.17.15"
 papaparse "^5.2.0"
```

I would like to update/force the version of `lodash` to be `4.17.20`. I found about [selective dependency resolution](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) and did the following in my `package.json`

```
"resolutions": {
  "csv-file-validator/lodash": "^4.17.20"
}
```

I removed my `yarn.lock`, the `node_modules` folder and ran `yarn install` once again. However, the lodash version is still 4.17.15

```
csv-file-validator@^1.8.0:
version "1.8.0"
resolved "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/RCTechnologies/EMA/_packaging/EMA/npm/registry/csv-file-validator/-/csv-file-validator-1.8.0.tgz#f8b879f533ce8c84b115d0ed2eca8e691249ec22"
integrity sha1-+Lh59TPOjISxFdDtLsqOaRJJ7CI=
dependencies:
  famulus "2.1.2"
  lodash "4.17.15"
  papaparse "^5.2.0"
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If so did I miss something, and what?

Answer (score 0):

`yarn.lock` will always show the dependencies declared in that version's `package.json`. You needed to check `lodash`'s entry instead which should look like

```
lodash@4.17.15, lodash@^4.17.20, <maybe other version strings>:
version "4.17.20"
...
```

while without that resolution you'd get

```
lodash@4.17.15, <maybe other version strings>:
version "4.17.15"
...
```

Or use `yarn why lodash`.